# how can I post content to wordpress through feedwordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have content xml structured to post it to wordpress through feedwordpress. I am receiving this through some Web Services and to be posted to wordpress.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Feed WordPress creates special template tags that you use to display the content from the feeds in your post and page templates.

#### The **[Wiki Documentation is very thorough](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/wiki/quick-start)** and will guide you through the process of getting it to work.